# C# with Selenium: "SelectElement" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to select something from a dropdownlist.
I can't figure out why am I getting an error. I've already initialized the following:

```
 using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
 using OpenQA.Selenium;
 using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
```

The error says: "SelectElement" does not exist in the current context.

```
 IWebDriver myDriver = new ChromeDriver();
 IWebElement currency = myDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("SelecInput"));
 var selectElement = SelectElement(currency);
 selectElement.SelectByText("qwe");
```

Sorry for the lack of knowledge. Just started studying C# with Selenium. Thanks for the help.

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to achieve, the error clearly states that you have not defined the method SelectElement

Comment: Oh. sorry. I'm trying to select something from a dropdownlist. How do I define the SelectElement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SelectElement is a constructor, you need to instantiate it.

```
var selectElement = new SelectElement(currency);
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I instantiate the SelectElement? 
The error says: "The type or namespace name 'SelectElement' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Try this: 
var selectElement = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement(currency);

If that did not work, make sure your form is not to set to "Client Profile".

Answer (score 2):

You need to install package WebDriver.Support first, it's a separate package from WebDriver.Selenium